# Combine animate.css and CSS attribute: display in the condition

Tags: jquery

Hi I have little problem with my script which should animate div when I click to hamburger menu then If you click to hamburger menu again It should close div (animation: slideOutUp). Problem is there when I use .css("display", "none") It doesnt animate anything and if I dont use .css("display", "none") It works but only once time, because It has display: block. There is complete website code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBxVbJ#anon-login

```
(function () {
  $('#hamburger-menu').on('click', function() {
    $('#bar').toggleClass('animate');
    if($('#menu-cover').css("display") == "none"){
       $('#menu-cover').css("display", "block").removeClass("slideOutUp").addClass("zoomIn");
    }
    else{
      $('#menu-cover').removeClass("zoomIn").addClass("slideOutUp").css("display", "none");
    }})
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the build in jQuery `slideToggle()` function.....

`$('#menu-cover').slideToggle();`

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/Unused/pen/yVxeGq)

The problem with the zoom in and your current CSS is the `display: none` on the div. Since the div is not visible... it won't zoom in. So you need to add the hidden class *first*. But this will cause the closed state class animation to be seen on page load. So, I also added the "hidden" class, then removed it via jquery. This is done so the initial page load wouldn't show the menu animation, but the animations will work with subsequent clicks.

Also, rather than the if/else statement, just using jquery's `toggleClass()` to swtch between two classes is cleaner.

`$('#menu-cover').removeClass('hidden').toggleClass('zoomInDown slideOutUp');`

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/Unused/pen/aBadbj)

```
<div id="menu-cover" class="animated slideOutUp hidden"></div>

(function () {
  $('#hamburger-menu').on('click', function() {
    $('#bar').toggleClass('animate');
    $('#menu-cover').removeClass('hidden').toggleClass("zoomInDown slideOutUp");
    })
})();
```